# Gulp uglify running but not working

Tags: javascript, gulp

I set up my gulp task to minify js, But when I run gulp through the command line it runs but nothing is added to the file.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('uglify-js');


 gulp.task('minifyjs', function(){

     return gulp.src('views/js/*.js');
       pipe(uglify()),
       pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
 });

 gulp.task('default',['minifyjs']);
```

Comment: Check where you run the gulp file, in this option you should stand same level with ```views/js/*.js```

Comment: When I put the gulpfile.js into the same file as the     views/js/*.js  it comes up as gulpfile not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you're running your Gulp task in such a project structure:

```
|
|_ Views
|   |_ JS
|       |_a.js
|_ gulpfile.js
```

Even in this case, try and make the folder `'./views/js/*.js'`, or `'/views/js/*.js'`

Comment: I tried putting it in the same file but its still comes up as gulpfile not being found.

Comment: You should put your Gulpfile in your root folder, from which you should run your gulp tasks in the console as well. The folder structure shown above assumes that your root folder also has the `views` folder which internally has the `JS` folder that has some `.js` files